# Cant get full body of http get request

Tags: http, flutter, dart

whenever I try to use http request the response doesn't contain the full body of the page , am I doing something wrong ?!

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> request() async {
  var response = await http.get("http://www.example.com/");
  print(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking it in you console then the buffer limit has reached that's why you are not able to see the output. May be you should check the size of the response body later if it matches the original response  then you will get the idea.

let me know if its working.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! , you are right, I did some research and for this kind of long output there is a function called `debugPrint` that can be used.

Comment: welcome if you find this answer helpful then marked as checked so that it will be helpful for others